# How can I specify both a file and a project folder when launching vscode?

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio-code

I've noticed that this will open a file with no project context:

```
$ code /path/to/some/file
```

and this will open the project context, but no file:

```
$ code /path/to/some/dir/
```

I want to write a bash function that does something like this:

```
vscode()
{
    pushd $(dirname $1)
    PROJECT_ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)         
    popd
    code --file $1 \
         --dir $PROJECT_ROOT
}
```

But that's not actually how vscode's command line interface works.  Is there some other way to launch vscode from the command line so that it knows about both the project and the file when it opens?

Ideally the chosen project folder would always be whichever git root is the file's most immediate parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it

```sh
code /path/to/file --add /path/to/folder/
```

The `--add` argument adds the folder to the current workspace.

**EDIT**: Tested and works on Windows 10 Build 19042.746, Code Version 1.52.1, x64.

Comment: How did I overlook that?  Thank you.  Combined with `-n` it's exactly what I was looking for.